# Is there a lazy functional (immutable) language where functions have intermediate variables+return?

Tags: scope, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

I apologize if this has an obvious answer. I would like to find a lazy functional programming language where the following pseudo code makes sense:

```
let f = function(x) {
    let y = x*x  // The variables y and z
    let z = y*2  // are local
    return z
}
```

Comment: why wouldn't it make sense? what's the issue here?

Comment: this makes sense in any language. Maybe functions as values aren't supported in many languages

Comment: In Haskell: `let f x = let y = x * x; z = y * 2 in z`. Haskell is lazy, functional and immutable.

Comment: Lazy/Functional then Haskel is the way to go.Good Luck!!  https://www.haskell.org/

Comment: Makes sense. I'm very new to these concepts and didn't know that Haskell could define local variables within functions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is, of course, doable in a functional, declarative language like haskell. Either with let bindings or where keyword. These are just chained together in one expression.

--local variables with 'where'

```
f :: Int -> Int
f x = z where
  z = y*2
  y = x*x
```

--local variables with let

```
g :: Int -> Int
g x =
   let y = x*x
       z = y*2
     in z
```

https://wiki.haskell.org/Let_vs._Where